# Jquery Load into div, specify the div in the link data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have made some search but have yet not found the solution. I want to load a page with jquery load by clinking on a link with rel but for the update, i want the jquery to locate the data in the link on which i have clicked and update the id of that data .

**Question :**
Instead of updating id_du_milieu i want the script to locate data-ajax="id_to_update" and update the div having the value of data-ajax which is id_to_update when you click on link one and update_id_2 when you click on link 2.

I do not want to add update_id_2 or id_to_update in the javascript but i want a jquery function that will take the value of data-ajax as id to update

This is my initial code

```
<a href="churches.php" rel="charger_tout" data-ajax="id_to_update">Link 1</a>
<div id=id_to_update></div> <a href="churches.php" rel="charger_tout" data-ajax="update_id_2">Link 2</a>
<div id=update_id_2></div>
```

Using

```
$('a[rel*=charger_tout]').on('click', function () {
  $('#id_du_milieu').html('<img src="images/facebook_style_loader.gif" />');
  $('#id_du_milieu').load($(this).attr('href'), function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    if (textStatus == 'error') {
      $('#id_du_milieu').html('<p>There was an error making the AJAX request</p>');
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using variable inside a selector, so you can do:

```
var myId = $(this).data('ajax');
$('#'+myId).html(/* insert some stuff here */);
```

On the other hand, if you want to address an element with data attribute (you didn't make that clear or I didn't understand well) you can do:

```
var myId = $(this).data('ajax');
$('a[data-ajax="+myId+"]').html(/* insert some stuff here */);
```

Instead of using jQuerys `$(this).data('ajax')` function you can also use `$(this).attr('data-ajax')` and that will equal the same. Data attributes are widely supported so unless you care about HTML validation you can use them even in IE4.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your first interpretation is correct. See the `<div>` below each `<a>`.